# angularx flatpickr Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Tags: angular, flatpickr

i want to use the datepicker plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-flatpickr in my angular project. But, when i having connected everything according to the instructions, I get an console error like this:

```
core.js:7187 ERROR DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at positionCalendar (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:125753:39)
    at open (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:125542:17)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:124528:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3271:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77647:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3270:60)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3043:47)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3346:34)
    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4541:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4567:17)
```

Please, help understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Could you please add the console text to your question instead of posting an external link to a screenshot? It will help more people look at and try to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: @Gene Z. Ragan, done

Answer (score 1):

I also came across a kind of similar issue and resolved it by import the flatpickr CSS as define below

```
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css'
```

Reference link of similar issue https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component/issues/150